# How do I download a website using python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Just an http get request like file_get_contents in php, or something simple where I enter URL and it get contents to variable.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/urllib.request.html

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use [urllib](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/urllib.request.html):

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
html = urlopen("http://www.stackoverflow.com/").read().decode('utf-8')
print(html)
```

Comment: And you can't assume it's UTF-8, really. Either don't decode it, or check the headers.

Comment: This only gets the HTML though. Is there a way to get images and external js files and stuff? Or do we just go through the html and look for the tags, because on some sites that takes a while

Comment: SSLCertVerificationError - resolved by using `import requests` instead

Answer (score 0):

Your Intention seems to be to get a static version of a Website. This can be achieved using WGET. This tool can in one command retrieve the files for a given URL.
Use the -r (recursive) Parameter with care, example:

wget -erobots=off -p -H -k -E -w 1 --random-wait -r -l 1 http://your.site.

[Download a working local copy of a webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348289/download-a-working-local-copy-of-a-webpage)