# Download a working local copy of a webpage

Tags: download, wget, offline-browsing

I would like to download a local copy of a web page and get all of the css, images, javascript, etc.

In previous discussions (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706934/download-an-offline-version-of-a-webpage) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/130306/suggestions-for-a-site-ripper), both of which are more than two years old), two suggestions are generally put forward: `wget -p` and [httrack](http://www.httrack.com).  However, these suggestions both fail.  I would very much appreciate help with using either of these tools to accomplish the task; alternatives are also lovely.

**Option 1: `wget -p`**

`wget -p` successfully downloads all of the web page's prerequisites (css, images, js).  However, when I load the local copy in a web browser, the page is unable to load the prerequisites because the paths to those prerequisites haven't been modified from the version on the web.

For example:

- In the page's html, `<link rel="stylesheet href="/stylesheets/foo.css" />` will need to be corrected to point to the new relative path of `foo.css`
- In the css file, `background-image: url(/images/bar.png)` will similarly need to be adjusted.

Is there a way to modify `wget -p` so that the paths are correct?

**Option 2: [httrack](http://www.httrack.com)**

`httrack` seems like a great tool for mirroring entire websites, but it's unclear to me how to use it to create a local copy of a single page.  There is a great deal of discussion in the httrack forums about this topic (e.g. [here](http://forum.httrack.com/readmsg/19088/index.html)) but no one seems to have a bullet-proof solution.

**Option 3: another tool?**

Some people have suggested paid tools, but I just can't believe there isn't a free solution out there.

Comment: If the answer doesn't work, try: `wget -E -H -k -K -p http://example.com` - only this worked for me. Credit: http://superuser.com/a/136335/94039

Comment: There is also software to do that, [Teleport Pro](http://www.tenmax.com/teleport/pro/home.htm).

Comment: `wget --random-wait -r -p -e robots=off -U mozilla http://www.example.com`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [download webpage and dependencies, including css images](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1581551/608639).

Comment: The way in which this question is closed, having 203K views to date, has explicit incremental requirements over other proposed and linked solutions.

Answer (score 293, accepted):

wget is capable of doing what you are asking. Just try the following:

```
wget -p -k http://www.example.com/
```

The `-p` will get you all the required elements to view the site correctly (css, images, etc).
The `-k` will change all links (to include those for CSS & images) to allow you to view the page offline as it appeared online.

From the Wget docs:

```
‘-k’
‘--convert-links’
After the download is complete, convert the links in the document to make them
suitable for local viewing. This affects not only the visible hyperlinks, but
any part of the document that links to external content, such as embedded images,
links to style sheets, hyperlinks to non-html content, etc.

Each link will be changed in one of the two ways:

    The links to files that have been downloaded by Wget will be changed to refer
    to the file they point to as a relative link.

    Example: if the downloaded file /foo/doc.html links to /bar/img.gif, also
    downloaded, then the link in doc.html will be modified to point to
    ‘../bar/img.gif’. This kind of transformation works reliably for arbitrary
    combinations of directories.

    The links to files that have not been downloaded by Wget will be changed to
    include host name and absolute path of the location they point to.

    Example: if the downloaded file /foo/doc.html links to /bar/img.gif (or to
    ../bar/img.gif), then the link in doc.html will be modified to point to
    http://hostname/bar/img.gif. 

Because of this, local browsing works reliably: if a linked file was downloaded,
the link will refer to its local name; if it was not downloaded, the link will
refer to its full Internet address rather than presenting a broken link. The fact
that the former links are converted to relative links ensures that you can move
the downloaded hierarchy to another directory.

Note that only at the end of the download can Wget know which links have been
downloaded. Because of that, the work done by ‘-k’ will be performed at the end
of all the downloads.
```

Comment: I tried this, but somehow internal links such as `index.html#link-to-element-on-same-page` stopped working.

Comment: Whole the site : http://snipplr.com/view/23838/downloading-an-entire-web-site-with-wget/

Comment: Some servers will response with a 403 code if you use wget without an User Agent, you can add `-U 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070802 SeaMonkey/1.1.4'`

Comment: does't this work if web site menus/links are implemented using java script?

Comment: doesn't get me background images

Comment: If you're finding you're still missing images etc.. then try adding this: -e robots=off ..... wget actually reads and respects robots.txt - this really made it hard for me to figure out why nothing worked!

Comment: to get resources from foreign hosts use `-H,  --span-hosts`

Comment: I made this for the same purpose: https://webjay.github.io/webtography/ It uses Wget and pushes the site to a repository on your GitHub account.

Comment: hey what if the link I want to replicate requires a session to work? for example if it's a page behind login?

Comment: @SabaAhang Fetch pages that are behind a login page. You need to replace user and password with the actual form fields while the URL should point to the Form Submit (action) page.
`wget ‐‐cookies=on ‐‐save-cookies cookies.txt ‐‐keep-session-cookies ‐‐post-data ‘user=labnol&password=123’ http://example.com/login.php
wget ‐‐cookies=on ‐‐load-cookies cookies.txt ‐‐keep-session-cookies http://example.com/paywall` [Full details here](https://www.labnol.org/software/wget-command-examples/28750/)

Comment: I have tried this to save a reddit page and it doesn't seem to save any of the images, graphics or css files on the webpage.

Comment: No parameters work for me at all, the query just go by wget ... url    when add a parameter it throw error .. and cant download full sourses

Comment: The documentation (https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Examples) claims, exg.: wget -m -k -K -E https://www.gnu.org/ -o /home/me/weeklog and it worked for me with: https://api.jquery.com/