# Scrape An Entire Website

Tags: html, web-scraping

I'm looking for recommendations for a program to scrape and download an entire corporate website.

The site is powered by a CMS that has stopped working and getting it fixed is expensive and we are able to redevelop the website.

So I would like to just get the entire website as plain html / css / image content and do minor updates to it as needed until the new site comes along.

Any recomendations?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download a working local copy of a webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6348289/608639)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Consider [HTTrack](http://www.httrack.com/). It's a free and easy-to-use offline browser utility.

> It allows you to download a World Wide Web site from the Internet to a local directory, building recursively all directories, getting HTML, images, and other files from the server to your computer.

Answer (score 75):

```
wget \
     --recursive \
     --no-clobber \
     --page-requisites \
     --html-extension \
     --convert-links \
     --restrict-file-names=windows \
     --domains www.website.com \
     --no-parent \
         www.website.com
```

Read more about it [here](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/downloading-entire-web-site-wget).

Comment: wget doesn't like `convert-links` and `no-clobber` used together. It will ignore the `no-clobber` in that case.

Comment: If you want to scrape a site with HTML5 tags such as audio or video, you have to use the latest version of wget. Support for those was added sometime in 2012-2013. I just compiled the latest from their Git repo and it got the web site I needed, complete with the video files.

Comment: Should `--domains` have the same argument as the name of the site to be scraped (in this case `website.com`, not `.org`)?

Comment: @lightrush Could you provide a version number, please?

Comment: You should add a `--wait=5` argument, as other answers do. Be considerate when scraping!

Comment: wget also respects the robots.txt file, so if you're still having trouble scraping, add `-e robots=off`.

Answer (score 57):

I know this is super old and I just wanted to put my 2 cents in.

`wget -m -k -K -E -l 7 -t 6 -w 5 http://www.website.com`

A little clarification regarding each of the switches:

`-m` Essentially, this means “mirror the site”, and it recursively grabs pages & images as it spiders through the site. It checks the timestamp, so if you run wget a 2nd time with this switch, it will only update files/pages that are newer than the previous time.

`-k` This will modify links in the html to point to local files. If instead of using things like `page2.html` as links throughout your site you were actually using a full `http://www.website.com/page2.html` you’ll probably need/want this. I turn it on just to be on the safe side – chances are at least 1 link will cause a problem otherwise.

`-K` The option above (lowercase k) edits the html. If you want the “untouched” version as well, use this switch and it will save both the changed version and the original. It’s just good practise in case something is awry and you want to compare both versions. You can always delete the one you didn’t want later.

`-E` This saves HTML & CSS with “proper extensions”. Careful with this one – if your site didn’t have .html extensions on every page, this will add it. However, if your site already has every file named with something like “.htm” you’ll now end up with “.htm.html”.

`-l 7` By default, the -m we used above will recurse/spider through the entire site. Usually that’s ok. But sometimes your site will have an infinite loop in which case wget will download forever. Think of the typical `website.com/products/jellybeans/sort-by-/name/price/name/price/name/price` example. It’s somewhat rare nowadays – most sites behave well and won’t do this, but to be on the safe side, figure out the most clicks it should possibly take to get anywhere from the main page to reach any real page on the website, pad it a little (it would suck if you used a value of 7 and found out an hour later that your site was 8 levels deep!) and use that #. Of course, if you know your site has a structure that will behave, there’s nothing wrong with omitting this and having the comfort of knowing that the 1 hidden page on your site that was 50 levels deep was actually found.

`-t 6` If trying to access/download a certain page or file fails, this sets the number of retries before it gives up on that file and moves on. You usually do want it to *eventually* give up (set it to 0 if you want it to try forever), but you also don’t want it to give up if the site was just being wonky for a second or two. I find 6 to be reasonable.

`-w 5` This tells wget to wait a few seconds (5 seconds in this case) before grabbing the next file. It’s often critical to use something here (at least 1 second). Let me explain. By default, wget will grab pages as fast as it possibly can. This can easily be multiple requests per second which has the potential to put huge load on the server (particularly if the site is written in PHP, makes MySQL accesses on each request, and doesn’t utilize a cache). If the website is on shared hosting, that load can get someone kicked off their host. Even on a VPS it can bring some sites to their knees. And even if the site itself survives, being bombarded with an insane number of requests within a few seconds can look like a DOS attack which could very well get your IP auto-blocked. If you don’t know for certain that the site can handle a massive influx of traffic, use the -w # switch.5 is usually quite safe. Even 1 is probably ok most of the time. But use something.

Answer (score 40):

None of the above got exactly what I needed (the whole site and all assets). This worked though.

First, follow [***this***](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-install-wget-om-mac-os-x-mountain-lion-mavericks-snow-leopard/) tutorial to get wget on OSX.

Then run this

```
wget --recursive --html-extension --page-requisites --convert-links http://website.com
```

Comment: Add --no-parent if you only want from a url and its subdomains

Comment: Make sure that you include the www. if the site forces www. otherwise it won't download anything.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to scrape it with `wget` as suggested in @Abhijeet Rastogi's answer.  If you aren't familiar with is then Blackwidow is a decent scraper.  I've used it in the past.  http://www.sbl.net/