# fetching grafana dashboard via wget or curl

Tags: linux, grafana

I would like to download a complete view of a grafana dashboard on linux terminal. When I try to use wget or curl, it only downloads some html, even if I add some delay for javascript.

I have tried to do this by using `wget -p -k...` command, and it works for other pages, not for grafana's dashboards.

Is there a way to download an html page fully rendered on linux terminal?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download a working local copy of a webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6348289/608639), [Scrape An Entire Website](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9265172/608639), etc.

Comment: Grafana is svg, not possible to fetch I think

Comment: @jww maybe not, I have already gone through similar SO pages but there is something special for grafana, maybe as Gilles Queno stated, it is because of svg.

Answer (score 0):

you can use curl and grafana  API   http://docs.grafana.org/http_api/dashboard/
this will give you output in json format
json you can pipe to jq   https://stedolan.github.io/jq/   to make preaty print or modify it

Comment: sure, but I did not bother myself with handling json, and plotting some graphs. but if I can not find any solution, then I will do, fetch json and plot, myself.

Comment: have you wrote solution with curl to request dashboard current valudes\data, or it's SQL quere result? if yes pleas post.