# Copy HTML, save all images on that page and redirect the images in the html

Tags: python, html

Here's what I want to do:

Hit a url,
save all of the html to a .html file
save all of the images
create a copy of that .html where all of the images are redirected to the local copy.

At this point, I can now open the second file while my computer is disconnected from the internet.

Here's what I'm doing right now just to pull the HTML:

```
urllib.urlretrieve(pageURL, "fileName.html")
```

Is there something I can just plug in to get this to work? I haven't managed to find any utilities.

Comment: Do you have to do this in Python? `wget -p -k` will do exactly what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348289/download-a-working-local-copy-of-a-webpage

Comment: It doesn't need to be in Python, but it's gotta work on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't need to be Python? Great. Try downloading [Wget for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm) and doing

`wget -p -k http://the-site-you-want.com/fileName.html`