# How to download links in the html of a url?

Tags: html, linux, curl, web, wget

For example, when I open https://stackoverflow.com/ in browser, the browser will download not only the main page, but also images, js, css.

But when I do `curl https://stackoverflow.com/`, only the main page html is downloaded. Is there any options of `curl` or `wget` that can download images/js/css also?

Or any other tools can do this?

Comment: possible duplicated? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348289/download-a-working-local-copy-of-a-webpage

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download a working local copy of a webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348289/download-a-working-local-copy-of-a-webpage)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wget -r` will save everything

```
wget -r www.your-site.com
```