# wget download webpage with images for local viewing

Tags: html, web-scraping, wget

Based on the discussion here: [download-a-working-local-copy-of-a-webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348289/download-a-working-local-copy-of-a-webpage), 
I am using following command to make download a webpage with the image:

```
wget --default-page -q -p -k http://mattvh.github.io/solar-theme-jekyll/index.html -O ./page_source/ex.html
```

For some urls this works, for others (as the one mentioned) this fails with error:

```
Cannot specify both -k or --convert-file-only and -O if multiple URLs are given, or in combination
with -p or -r. See the manual for details.
```

How to fix this?

Comment: figured what was wrong. What I wanted to achieve with -O was to replace index.html with a specific name. However wget understands -O as putting all the contents in a single file. I need to do the renaming of index.html outside of wget. I will still leave the question here because it might be useful.